# Cannot change directory using system() in C++

Tags: c++, cmd, system, cd

As the title says, I cannot use "cd" in even a super simple C++ program. More accurately, I CAN use it (i.e. it compiles and doesn't throw any errors) but it carries on as if I haven't.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    system("cd");
    system("dir");

    system("cd C:\\Users\\Sajado");
    system("dir");

    return 0;
}
```

The output window returns the directory listing of the project directory both times. I have also tried using paths other folders, both higher and lower, and
`cd ..`
has no effect either.

I am using codeblocks if that helps. I'm no C++ or cmd expert by any means so I may be missing something very obvious. Anyone know why this might be misbehaving?

Comment: The `system()` calls are independent. You will get a new environment each time. To do what you want create a batch file and execute that from cmd.exe in a single `system()`.

Comment: Why not using `chdir`?

Answer (score 6):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722407/3336423), you need to do:

```
system("cd C:\\Users\\Sajado && dir");
```

Because

> The changed directory only lasts for the duration of the system
>   command. The command starts a separate program, which inherits its
>   current directory from your program, but when that program exits its
>   current directory dies with it.

Comment: Ah OK. Thanks for everyone's answers. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As commented @drescherjm pointed out, `system` calls are interpreted in isolation of each other so if you change the working directory in one it will not be reflected in a subsequent call.

You can do this:
`system("cd C:\\Users\\Sajado && dir");` or, better yet, use an argument to the `dir` command: `system("dir C:\\Users\\Sajado");`