# Unable to create tar file of files from specific folder . Getting wrong path after extraction

Tags: c, system

Here I want to create tar file of **bin folder only** . My main.c code has location i.e. /home/amit/practice/datafill/main.c. datafill directory contains folders like bin, conf, config, data,lib.

There is one  link [system("cd <path>") in a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722368/systemcd-path-in-a-c-program)  But it doesn't solve my problem . with the use of combining 2 commands with && operator it is creating bin.tar from bin folder only ,but when it is extracted, it is containing full path link **/home/amit/practice/datafill/bin/** which is wrong .Suppose there is one file abc.txt inside bin folder . So after extraction ,abc.txt should have path as **bin/abc.txt** only, not **/home/amit/practice/datafill/bin/abc.txt**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
char Cmd[256];
/*Go to specific directory && create tar file*/
sprintf(Cmd,"cd /home/amit/practice/datafill/bin/ && sudo tar -cvf bin.tar *");
system(Cmd);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates the tar file in the `bin` directory, but it appears you checked an older attempt in the current directory.

This code is strange and unnatural. I would normally do something like this:

```
 `cd /home/amit/practice/datafill/bin/ && sudo tar -cvf - *`
```

which causes the tarball is written to the program's standard output. If you want to generate it to a specific path, this would be more reasonable

```
 `sudo sh -c '(cd /home/amit/practice/datafill/bin/ && tar -cvf - *) > bin.tar'`
```

Comment: its working properly but what is meaning of  tar -cvf - * part ,  Suppose in bin folder there is one file named abc.txt . is possible to exclude that file from bin folder while creating the tar file? .what changes need to be done in this command. ?

Comment: @user3559780: There are ways but I recommend abandoning the `system` API and designing the thing more robustly for such a complicated job.

Comment: fine ,but what is meaning of tar -cvf  - * part?? .because this is different than normal command for example. tar -cvf bin.tar bin

Comment: @user3559780: - where a file name goes means stdin/stdout. In this case stdout. So we redirect outside the cd.

Comment: do u have any link or document where I can get more information about it ? I am searching on internet about it .but not found about it yet